# Windows 10 Desktop lagging

Tags: windows-10, lag

I've been having this problem with my Windows 10 Desktop PC, where as I start the computer it works absolutely fine. Run the PC for a few minutes and windows take forever to load, desktop shows through windows, 'Okay' buttons don't show up, Virtual Machines run like garbage (not the main point) and the computer is just overall slow. It's so annoying. Sometimes when I play CS:GO the problem kind of fixes itself but not all the time, but it's not that effective to have to game every time I want to use the machine. I don't know if I have a virus or something. I've been debating on whether or not to just reinstall Windows, but I have too much data, such as video editing assets, that it would be a pain to relink it all.

Specs:
CPU - Core-i3-4160 @ 3.60 gHz
 - GPU - AMD Radeon 5700 HD
 - RAM - 8GB DDR3 (7.44GB usable)
 - Storage: 1TB HDD 200GB used

Comment: 1. Was this initially a Windows 7 machine that you upgraded?                                                                                                           
2. Did your machine ever work normally?

Comment: Sounds like a hdd I/O problem

Comment: no, my computer was originally windows 8 and I upgraded, not a clean install i did an upgrade. And yes, thorugh the time I had windows 8 and through part of the lifetime of it having windows 10 it worked fine

Comment: Take a peek in Task Manager. Look for processes eating excessive CPU, RAM, or HDD.

Comment: If the problem recur with no clear pattern, I suspect it is an antivirus, or system process. Windows 10 is not known for its considerate timing for updates. Sometimes Google updater is also the culprit.

Do you run an Insider Windows 10?